# Loop is not working for email send in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework.
I have written code for sending emails like this:

```
$this->emailcomm->sendemail($data) ;
```

but it is in loop. It is working for only once. It is not return any response after send the email.

I have tried like below:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($keyarray);$i++)
{
 $data=array(
'to' => $keyarray[$i],  
 'from' => 'test' ,
subject' => 'test Order',
'message' => ('Please see attached sales order placed ),
'attach'  =>$array[$keyarray[$i]]['pdf']
);
$this->emailcomm->sendhtml_email($data);
}
```

in emailcomm library i have written like below:

```
function sendhtml_email($info)
{
$this->CI->email->clear();
$this->CI->email->from('reports@gmail.com','Test Reports'); 
$this->CI->email->to($this->to);
$this->CI->email->subject($this->subject);
$this->CI->email->message($this->message);
$this->CI->email->attach($path.$this->attach,'attachment');
if($this->CI->email->send())
{
$this->CI->email->clear(TRUE);
return 1;
}
}
```

It send the email only once. I need it run howmany times in loop. And it does not give any output like above return 1 after send the email. Please advice me.

Comment: You must get error on your loop for this code:
'message' => ('Please see attached sales order placed )

Comment: That is sample. It is working for first email. it is stopped at first email only. it is not go to next email in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($keyarray);$i++)
{
 $data=array(
'to' => $keyarray[$i],  
 'from' => 'test' ,
subject' => 'test Order',
'message' => '(Please see attached sales order placed )',
'attach'  =>$array[$keyarray[$i]]['pdf']
);
$this->emailcomm->sendhtml_email($data);
}
```

In emailcomm library i have written like below:

```
public function sendhtml_email($info)
{
$this->CI->load->library('email');
//$this->CI->email->clear(); //No Need
$this->CI->email->from('reports@gmail.com','Test Reports'); 
$this->CI->email->to($this->to);
$this->CI->email->subject($this->subject);
$this->CI->email->message($this->message);
$this->CI->email->attach($path.$this->attach,'attachment');
if($this->CI->email->send())
{
/*$this->CI->email->clear(TRUE);
return 1;*/ //No need
}
}
```

**Ref:**
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: i added library in my controller and i tried with no return statements also. but it is not working.

Comment: In function please check info param is coming or not?

Comment: It is coming but only once. If we place return statement before send function it return 2 values and 2 email values.

Comment: then you need to call by reference. You need to pass reference in param